# Icons not showing?

Tags: css, icons

Icons not showing , So I've this problem.

I'm using some weather icons provided by erikflowers on github.

They are working and showing up fine when I've opened my app through the live server extension in Visual Studio Code. However, when I open my index.html manually from the folder, they are showing up as blank squares.

Anyone have any clue why this might be?

Thanks in advance

[image: in live server]

[image: Manual]

EDIT:

[image: errors]

Directory:
[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./weather-icons-wind.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./weather-icons.css">
```

I did try changing to ./ no help

It says it can't find the files but they are there

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you haven't got the icon files in the right directory. Can you show us a minimal example of the code  you are using. Also, are you seeing any errors in your browser's dev tools console?

Comment: Edited the post just there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pathing is wrong. As u wrote by urself in a comment -

"To use the Weather Icons, place the main CSS files in your CSS **directory**, and the font files in a "font" directory on the same folder level as the CSS director. Once you've done that, all you need to do to reference an icon in your HTML is type ""<i class="wi wi-night-sleet""> "

You dont have a CSS **directory**.

Also look at your console error.
The route is wrong.. your Project Name is missing.
"../JavaScript/Projects/fonts/weather..", where is your Folder "Weather API"?

I would suggest to create a CSS folder (your styles.css stays in the project root), with your icon stylesheet files in it. That should fix your problems.

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing those icons? CDN? Or do you have them stored locally in some separate folder? Also, share your `index.html` and folder structure.

For example, you have them in a folder called `icons`, say a file called `cloud.png`. Then there are 2 ways to access them in your HTML file:

1. Using `icons/cloud.png`
2. Using `./icons/cloud.png`

Both of these approaches work in Live Server, but sometimes we have to use the 2nd one when opening `index.html` directly or when hosting on Github Pages.
So try both of them and see which one works for you.

Comment: I have the icons stored locally. "To use the Weather Icons, place the main CSS files in your CSS directory, and the font files in a "font" directory on the same folder level as the CSS director. Once you've done that, all you need to do to reference an icon in your HTML is type "<i class="wi wi-night-sleet"></i>" . So this is exactly how I have them stored.